# Copying files one-by-one but maintaining folder structure

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to Powershell and I'm currently making a backup tool.

What I am having trouble with is creating a script to copy files one by one but maintain any folder structure that is there (completely user-proof).

The reason I am doing it one-by-one is so that I can check if it succeeded/failed as I go and output it to an object to create a HTML report out of the results.

The idea is something like this:

```
function initCopy () {
    $global:objects = @()
    $contents = Get-ChildItem -recurse -path $f_from_path
    foreach ($item in $contents) {
        $str = "$item   "
        try {
            Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $f_to_path -Force -ErrorVariable err_Copy -ErrorAction Stop
            $global:objects += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                Name = $item.Name
                OldPath = $item.FullName
                Result = "Success"
        } 
        $str += "Success"
        }
        catch {
            $str += "Failure : $err_Copy"
            $global:objects += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                Name = $item.Name
                OldPath = $item.FullName
                Result = "Failure"
            } 
        $str += "Failure"
        }
        echo $str >> $output_path
    }
    $global:object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
    return $true
}
```

Also, would love an example as to how to create an HTML table out of the outputted object. Quite confusing, though I have an idea.

```
$head = @" 
  <title>Backup Report: $backupName</title>
  <style>
  Body {
    font-family "Calibri", "Arial", sans-serif;
    background-color:#252525;
  }
  table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:60%
  }
  td {
    font-size:12pt;
    border:1px #ffa500 solid;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  }
  th {
    font-size:14pt;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    background-color:#ffa500;
    color:#252525;
  }
  name tr {
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#ffa500;
  }
  </style>
"@
$html = $global:object | Select "Name","Result" | ConvertTo-Html -Head $head -precontent "<h2>Backup Report for $backupName</h2>" -PostContent "<h6> Report run at $cdt on $cdd</h6>" | Out-String
```

Comment: Could you give an example? As you can see in my code it has a simple "Success" or "Failure" feature, and I am not sure how that could be done with robocopy.

Comment: Okay so I've had a look at Robocopy and I just cannot use any of the results and manage them, unless I create some dodgy parser that fails 9/10. Copy-Item is the way to go, I just need to figure out a way of doing it file-by-file while maintaining file structure.

Comment: Would be too much work to have to install / copy that onto any computer that I use this program on. It is supposed to be backup software that I can quickly copy to a computer and setup to backup a folder daily/weekly or whatever. Quick and easy, however the way this is done makes it a bit messy.

It isn't very convenient to constantly use a third-party cmdlet either.

Answer (score 0):

To copy files and sub-folders one-by-one in PowerShell, you'll need to alter the destination path for each file copy.  And you'll need to handle sub-folders differently than files:

```
$f_from_path = "C:\Users\Michael\Documents"
$f_to_path = "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Test"

$contents = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $f_from_path
foreach ($item in $contents) {
    $newPath = $item.FullName
    $newPath = $newPath.Replace($f_from_path, $f_to_path)
    if ($item.PSIsContainer) {
        #Write-Host ("Directory " +  $item.FullName)
        try {
            New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $newPath -Force -ErrorVariable err_Copy -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        }
        catch {}
    }
    else {
        #Write-Host ("File      " +  $item.FullName)
        try {
            Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $newPath -Force -ErrorVariable err_Copy -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch {}
    }
}
```

Error handling not shown.

As for HTML output, I haven't tried the PowerShell cmdlets for HTML, but you can always output the HTML tags and values to a plain text output file, i.e. using Add-Content to write the HTML line-by-line.  Add-Content can be slower than using StreamWriter classes from .NET.